# Drivetrain stuttering on 2001 F-150 automatic

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, vibration, f-150, torque-converter

I have a 2001 F-150 with what I believe to be the 4R70W transmission. It's a 4 speed automatic with the 4.6L engine.

The past two times I have driven it I have gotten a massive shaking and stuttering from the drivetrain. Each time it happens after accelerating when trying to maintain speed going uphill. Just beforehand the engine RPMs drop down, which I presume is the torque converter lockup attempting to engage.

Even though the truck is stuttering, the engine maintains speed just fine.

If I accelerate, the stuttering stops immediately.

Could something be preventing the torque converter from locking up? Or is there another possible cause of this? The transmission has 285,000 miles on it.

Comment: Fluid level correct? When was the last time the automatic trans filter and fluid has been changed.

Comment: Fluid is on the dipstick hashed area. Changed fluid and filter at 260000 miles. Was able to change 12 quarts of fluid, I guess a couple are in the cooler.

Comment: Did it act this way before having the fluid/filter change?

Comment: does this happen only on hills?

Comment: @CharlieRB that was years ago, no it did not happen then.

Comment: @Ben only on uphills so far. There are not really any flat roads here.

Comment: TCC shudder is common for Fords. The true fix is to rebuild the transmission. I've heard of replacing the Ford fluid with ATF+4 (a Chrysler fluid) helping to reduce or eliminate TCC shudder but it is no guarantee.